# How can I create a Package for a single Python file?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

I'm currently experimenting with Python packages. I have a tiny project which I would like to share with some people. This project consists of exactly one Python file, so I thought it should not be too difficult to create a Python package for it.

I've managed to register the project with the following setup.py at PyPI:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='LumixMaptool',
    version='1.0.4',
    author='Martin Thoma',
    author_email='info@martin-thoma.de',
    packages=['lumix-maptool'],
    scripts=['lumix-maptool/lumix-maptool.py'],
    url='http://pypi.python.org/pypi/LumixMaptool/',
    license='LICENSE',
    description='Manage GPS information for Panasonic Lumix cameras.',
    long_description="""Panasonic offers GPS metadata to add to a SD card. This metadata can contain
tourist information that might be useful for sightseeing. This maptool helps
to copy the data from Lumix DVD to the SD card that is inserted into your 
computer (the camera has not to be connected).""",
    install_requires=[
        "argparse >= 1.2.1",
        "pyparsing >= 2.0.1",
        "pyparsing >= 2.0.1",
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts':
            ['lumixmaptool = lumixmaptool:main']
    }
)
```

with the command

```
python setup.py register
```

and later updated with

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

Now it's here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LumixMaptool

But I currently have problems with the following entries:

- `packages`
- `scripts`
- `entry_points`

What do I have to fill in there? Do I have to have a certain project structure / some files?

I currently have:

- Readme.txt
- LICENSE.txt
- setup.py
- lumix-maptool.py

The projects GitHub site is here: https://github.com/MartinThoma/lumix_map_tool

Answer (score 0):

Every package on PyPI needs to have a file called `setup.py` at the root of the directory. If your’e using a markdown-formatted read me file you’ll also need a `setup.cfg` file. Also, you’ll want a `LICENSE.txt` file describing what can be done with your code. So if I’ve been working on a library called `mypackage`, my directory structure would look like this:

```
root-dir/   # arbitrary working directory name
        setup.py
        setup.cfg
        LICENSE.txt
        README.md
        mypackage/
            __init__.py
            foo.py
            bar.py
            baz.py
```

Refer this [link](http://pypix.com/python/create-python-library/) to know more about packaging.

- **Entry Point**

EntryPoints provide a persistent, filesystem-based object name registration and name-based direct object import mechanism (implemented by the setuptools package).

They associate names of Python objects with free-form identifiers. So any other code using the same Python installation and knowing the identifier can access an object with the associated name, no matter where the object is defined. The associated names can be any names existing in a Python module; for example name of a class, function or variable. The entry point mechanism does not care what the name refers to, as long as it is importable.

An "entry point" is typically a function (or other callable function-like object) that a developer or user of your Python package might want to use, though a non-callable object can be supplied as an entry point as well (as correctly pointed out in the comments!).

The most popular kind of entry point is the "console_script" entry point, which points to a function that you want made available as a command-line tool to whoever installs your package.

- **Packages**

Packages are used to include all the python packages present in your root-dir. you can use `find_packages()`.

For simple projects, it's usually easy enough to manually add packages to the packages argument of setup(). However, for very large projects (Twisted, PEAK, Zope, Chandler, etc.), it can be a big burden to keep the package list updated. That's what `setuptools.find_packages()` is for. Refer [docs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#using-find-packages).

- **Scripts**

Refer this [docs](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/command-line-scripts.html#the-scripts-keyword-argument) for scripts.

Comment: Could you please also answer my question about the `setup.py` (What should I have in `packages`, `scripts` and `entry_points`)?

Comment: And please note: I don't want to write a library. My code should be executable from an enduser, but it will not be included in other code.